# LWC @api decoration

Tags: api, lightning-web-components

Why do I have to decorate private (@track) with @api in this code

```
 @api showCart = false;
 @api showMe() {
    this.showCart = true;
}
```

without @api decoration I've got an error means that 'There is no property showCart in component'

Can anyone explain me some details about this?

Answer (score 3):

[As per documentation:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_decorators.html) If this property needs to be accessible by a parent component and other sibling components, it needs to be `@api` enabled. This also means the value of the property is going to be listening for changes.

> "To expose a public property, decorate it with @api. Public properties define the API for a component. An owner component that uses the component in its markup can access the component’s public properties. Public properties are reactive. If the value of a reactive property changes, the component rerenders. When a component rerenders, all the expressions used in the template are reevaluated.
>   See Public Properties.
>   To expose a public method, decorate it with @api. Public methods are part of a component’s API. To communicate down the containment hierarchy, owner and parent components can call JavaScript methods on child components."

Comment: Does it mean that if i want to call showMe() method from parent  i have to (in my case) always decorate showCart with @api?

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are simply functions that are prefixed with @symbol and placed immediately before the code being decorated.

`@api` decorator

It provides public property
It provides reactive property
Use this decorator to expose public property of a web component.